# NameError: name 'blank' is not defined

Tags: nameerror

I'm typing a code that holds all of my account information for all of my different accounts so that if I ever forget I can run this code and find it.

However, I keep receiving an error stating that AccountInfo is not defined. I've tried a lot of things and have looked at a lot of forums but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing incorrectly.

Can you help me? I've taken out pretty much the whole code for "AccountInfo" because I don't want to put that information.

```
def Main():
myUsername = input("What is the username? (Case sensitive)")
if(myUsername == "Brandon13"):
    myPassword = input("What is the password? (Case sensitive)")
    if(myPassword == "13Dominators4JC!"):
        AccountInfo()
    else:
        print("I'm sorry! You entered incorrect information!")
        Main()
else:
    print("I'm sorry! You entered incorrect information!")
    Main()  

Main()      


def AccountInfo():
    myAccount = input("Which account information would you like access to? (Case sensitive)")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, first, you declare the Main function.  Then you call the Main function, which calls the AccountInfo function before it's defined.  *Then* you declare the AccountInfo function.

Move the AccountInfo function to the top of your code to solve the problem.

Comment: Doing this ran AccountInfo, but it did so without asking for a username or password fist which was the Main() function. How do I have my Main() function run first?

Comment: Move the AccountInfo declaration to the top of the script, not the call to it